# XML::Compile and xsd getting errors

Tags: xml, perl, xsd

an extract of the xsd file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
           xmlns="http://www.derivatexxl.de/derivatexxl/v1.1" 
           targetNamespace="http://www.derivatexxl.de/derivatexxl/v1.1" 
           elementFormDefault="qualified" 
           attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
  <xs:include schemaLocation="derivatexxlTypes.xsd"/>
  <!-- Root -->
  <xs:element name="DERIVATEXXL">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="DELIVERY"/>
        <xs:element ref="GENERAL_INFORMATION" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element ref="SENDER"/>
        <xs:element ref="ISSUER"/>
        <xs:element ref="PRODUCT" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
```

My code:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use XML::Compile::Cache;
use XML::Compile::Util qw/pack_type/;

my $xsds = ['derivatexxlTypes.xsd', 'derivatexxl_110.xsd'];
my $schema = XML::Compile::Cache->new($xsds);
# This works, it prints all the available definitions
$schema->printIndex();
my $type = pack_type 'http://www.derivatexxl.de/derivatexxl/v1.1', 'DERIVATEXXL';
warn $schema->template('PERL' => $type);
```

I get this error message back:
"regexp error : failed to compile: Expecting a char range"

If I change the last line to:
    warn $schema->template('PERL' => 'DERIVATEXXL');

I get the error:
"error: cannot find element or attribute `DERIVATEXXL'"

To tell you the truth, I'm not sure if I just don't get it, or if XML::Compile can't work with these xsd files...

I'd be very grateful for any help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message "regexp error ..." suggests that the schema processor is objecting to a regular expression in the schema, which means the problem will be on an `xsd:pattern` element.  The XSD schema document you show does not contain any pattern elements, so it would appear that the problem is in the schema document `derivatexxlTypes.xsd`.

The description of the problem ("Expecting a char range") suggests that the parser has found a left square bracket in the expression and thinks it has seen the beginning of a character range (which takes the form `a-z` or similar), but not the ending.  Note that in XSD 1.0, unlike Perl, some processors are apt to have trouble with expressions like `[a-zA-Z.-]` -- if you want a hyphen in the character group, escape it:  `[a-zA-Z.\-]`.

The error message you get when you change your code looks to me like a secondary problem.  You know already that the processor is not succeeding in compiling the schema, and when you ask it for a particular element in the schema it is not surprising that it cannot find the element:  it couldn't compile the schema, so when it's looking for an element or attribute named DERIVATEXXL in the compiled schema, it's looking in an empty schema.  (But I am not a user of XML::Compile; this is speculation.)

Comment: Spot on! Using xmllint I've found the problematic patterns. Thank you so much for your help.